# Object.fromEntries only available on iOS? (react native - NOT WEB)

Tags: javascript, react-native, object, ecmascript-6, expo

The title is pretty self explanatory but still, consider this sample code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Constants } from 'expo';


export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return ( 
      <Text>
         {Object.fromEntries("test")}
      </Text>
    );
  }
}
```

Check it out on [Expo Snacks](https://snack.expo.io/@iuliu/942977)

By opening it on an **Android** device, I get the error that the `fromEntries` function does not exist on `Object`:

[image]

But on iOS, it does exist:

[image]

(bad parameter supplied to it, but it exists, nevertheless)

So what's happening here? Aren't JS engines supposed to be identical between the 2 platforms? What other known discrepancies like these exist?

Comment: Just to add browsers are by no-means the same. They all have varying JS engines, rendering engines etc etc. They all have their own priorities on implementing the spec and their own agenda on their preferred version of the spec. [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/) is a good resource for browser compat.

Comment: Check the official spec-compliant polyfill: https://github.com/es-shims/Object.fromEntries

Comment: it just depends what javascript engine is used in the particular OS, some newer Android version support this, some don´t

Comment: This question is about REACT-NATIVE guys, what browsers? What Android version? The engine is shipped with the app itself..

Answer (score 6):

Most likely you have an old or not-fully-supported engine (check the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)). You can make an ES6 polyfill like this:

```
Object.fromEntries = Object.fromEntries || arr => arr.reduce((acc, [k, v]) => (acc[k] = v, acc), {});
```

Or an ES5 polyfill like this:

```
Object.fromEntries = Object.fromEntries || function(arr) {
    return arr.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
        acc[curr[0]] = curr[1];
        return acc;
    }, {});
};
```

Comment: why are you assigning value to `Object.fromEntries`? from the docs it takes key value pairs and converts it to an object.

Comment: @TenTenPeter It's a polyfill - if it doesn't exist, then you can use this one. Hold on, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I mean.. I know this is fixable... but.. why is it like this? How can "I" have an old or unsupported engine? I'm just using RN.

Comment: I honestly don't know @iuliu.net, but try implementing the polyfills above and see how you go.

Comment: Once again, thanks for your solution to "how to solve this", but my question wasn't really "how to solve this", but rather "why is it like this?". I want to know if this is something I can expect and will have to protect against in the future or is just a RN bug. Appreciate your answer nevertheless.

Comment: some functions are not available in react native, dependning on the engine that's being used. Like there are functions that are not available in node v6 but are in node v7.

Answer (score 1):

just add the babel preset to your babel config:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-object-from-entries

Answer (score 0):

Functions like [.flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat#Browser_compatibility), `Object.fromEntries`, and some new ones are not yet supported by most browsers and Javascript engines. Which means we might see it being supported in the next update of android or iOS Javascript engines. [support chart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries#Browser_compatibility)

[image: support]

Comment: Again, question is about react native... not browsers.

Comment: I'm giving you an example, of the current support, as you can see from there it is not currenlty supported by react native engine and a lot of browsers.

Comment: and I said this in my answer *not yet supported by most browsers and Javascript engines.*

Comment: "as you can see from there it is not currenlty supported by react native ". If you read my question, you noticed it IS supported by react native, but only on iOS. And React Native is supposed to run on the same engine irrespective of platform, hence my confusion. But I think you're confusing web apps, which run on which ever engine it's available, and React Native, which is supposed to run on the same engine across any platform to ensure consistency. https://www.reactnative.guide/3-react-native-internals/3.1-react-native-internals.html